# it doesn't show the figure but just a frame and inside the file name, although the image file is uploaded in the same folder on overleaf

Tags: latex

May the problem consist in wrong packages? The image was uploaded successfully in the folder I tried even with the function wrapfigure but the result is the same. And I tried to use the image not through the \newcommand but it cannot be read properly anyway.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\graphicspath{ {images/} }

        
\usepackage [a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=0cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\textheight=5000px                    % Saving trees ;-)
\usepackage{url}


%%% Macros
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}          % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{15em}}      % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\titolo}[4]{

**\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{logoPolimi.png}
\centering
\end{figure}**

%\vspace*{15em}
\sepspace

\centering\textbf{\huge{#1}}
\vspace{15em}

\centering\textbf{#2}

\vspace{2em}
\textbf{#3}

\vspace{2em}
\textbf{#4}}



\usepackage{caption}
%\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}



 \titolo{Digital Channel}{Mario Rossi}{Management Engineering}{Politecnico di Milano}
 

  \end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The figure does not appear, because you are using `draft` as document class option.

Unrelated to your problem, but

- font commands like `\huge` are switches and don't take an argument. So instead of `\huge{...}`, you should use `{\huge ...}`
- you don't need the `graphics` package if you also load `graphicx`
- if your tex distribution is up to date, you can also skip `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` because this is the default for some years

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,
%draft
]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]
%\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\graphicspath{ {images/} }

        
\usepackage [a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=0cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\textheight=5000px                    % Saving trees ;-)
\usepackage{url}


%%% Macros
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}          % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{15em}}      % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\titolo}[4]{

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image.png}
\centering
\end{figure}

%\vspace*{15em}
\sepspace

\centering\textbf{\huge #1}
\vspace{15em}

\centering\textbf{#2}

\vspace{2em}
\textbf{#3}

\vspace{2em}
\textbf{#4}}



\usepackage{caption}
%\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}



 \titolo{Digital Channel}{Mario Rossi}{Management Engineering}{Politecnico di Milano}
 







  \end{document}
```

[image]