# Overleaf doesn't insert picture and shows empty rectangle

Tags: latex, overleaf

This is the code snippet. The image is in the same location as the main .tex file and all I get is a rectangle with the name of the image.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=4cm]{B7oiUtYdkK-rb-case-3.png}
        \caption{Insertie cazul 3}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Can you report the error message that you get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [it doesn't show the figure but just a frame and inside the file name, although the image file is uploaded in the same folder on overleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66237572/it-doesnt-show-the-figure-but-just-a-frame-and-inside-the-file-name-although-t)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when you have the document set to `draft` mode.
You may have set it as document class option like `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{article}`, or maybe it is selected in the compiler options, as shown in this guide: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Images_not_showing_up

> The Fast [draft] mode skips some steps in order to speed-up
> compilation, and often doesn't show included images.

[image]